# Error in reading input from another file to a c program

Tags: c, gcc

I had been trying to read input from a file to a c code, but something is going wrong. Program is able to read input but not displaying expected output. Here is my c code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
void call_me(char* ptr){
    system(ptr);
}
int main(){
    char str[10];
    read(0,str,100);
    call_me(str);
    printf("executed");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run above code in terminal as:

```
./sys
```

and give /bin/sh as input, it leads me to shell.
But on using :

```
cat file | ./sys
```

it only prints executed.
Here content of file is:

```
/bin/sh
```

Comment: `char str[10];
    read(0,str,100);` ? `10` != `100`. Also `read` does not read zero terminated data - if you want them to be zero terminated (and pass to `system` which expects z zero terminated string) you have to terminate it yourself. So handle the return value of `read`.

Comment: have you tried to  `printf(str);` to see what are you reading?